# How do I Perform an Xlookup within VBA with a wildcard cell range?

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

For a VBA application I am trying to look for wildcard matches (before or after variable) in another sheet.

```
Application.XLOOKUP("*" & Mod_SelectColumns.PnPRefRange & "*", Worksheets("Worksheetname").Range("C3:C119"), Worksheets("Worksheetname").Range("B3:B119"), "NOT FOUND", 2).
```

`Mod_SelectColumns.PnPRefRange` is a global Range variable.

For some reason I can't manage to combine the "*" (wildcard symbols) with the variable.

How can I manage that?

I tried using a string range as a place holder, this does work.

Comment: `Mod_SelectColumns.PnPRefRange` doesn't look like a variable when it contains a `.`

Comment: Hi BigBen, I understand the confusion, it is a global variable referencing to another module.

Comment: Global variable sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Really would you be so kind to elaborate why?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=avoid+global+variables+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I was aware of the problem but not the solution. I found a solution for my problem. I will add it as a reply in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can loop through your range and perform XLOOKUPS that way. Here's an example sub statement using two tables on two seperate worksheets:

```
Sub FruitXlookup()

    Dim Lookuptring As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SelectedCell As String
    Dim LookupCell As String
    
        For i = 2 To 9
        SelectedCell = "B" & CStr(i)
        LookupCell = "A" & CStr(i)
        Range(SelectedCell) = Application.XLOOKUP("*" & Range(LookupCell) & "*", Worksheets("LookupSheet").Range("A2:A5"), Worksheets("LookupSheet").Range("B2:B5"), "NOT FOUND", 2)
        Next i

 
End Sub
```